# Any free tools for webservice testing with NTLM2 support?

Tags: web-services, testing, automation

What tools are free tools are available for testing WebServices that are behind NTLM2 authentication.

SoapUI Is Excellent tool with all functionality that I need, however, it doesn't support NTLMv2. If someone has a way of making that work, please provide solution.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing up a custom web service testing app ought to be a pretty simple thing to do...

Comment: It is actually pretty hard if you want to do any load testing. Or be able to have a generic tool for multiple requests. It is definitely not cost effective.